# Getting robolectric to work with android compatibility package

Tags: android, robolectric

I try to use Robolectric to run tests for my Android application, which is using the android-support package. In my onCreate() method I call

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Unfortunately, getSupportLoaderManager() returns null here. Do I have to prepare anything to make the compatiblity classes available to robolectric?

I have the android.jar (android-8) and the android-support-v4.jar in the classpath in my test project, along with robolectric-1.2 snapshot version.

Test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class HoebAppActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldStartActivity() {
            final MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
            System.out.println(activity.getSupportLoaderManager()); // return null

            activity.onCreate(null);
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
System.out.println(Robolectric.directlyOnFullStack(activity)
            .getSupportLoaderManager());
```

outputs android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl@9a90b9 so I guess, I just need to feed this back to the activity? Seems like I am getting closer here.

Edit2: I tried to bind my own ShadowFragmentActivity:

```
@Implements(FragmentActivity.class)
public class ShadowFragmentActivity extends
    com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowFragmentActivity {
@RealObject
private FragmentActivity realActivity;

@Implementation
public LoaderManager getSupportLoaderManager() {
    return Robolectric.directlyOnFullStack(realActivity)
            .getSupportLoaderManager();
}
}
```

bound with

```
Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowFragmentActivity.class);
```

This appears to work for the moment. I will have to try further to see if it does what I want. No idea if this is in any way the correct way to go or not.

Comment: Can you share some code please? Also are you able to get a basic Robolectric test running in your test project? This is just to verify that you have configured all the dependencies correctly.

Comment: if I remove the getSupportLoaderManager() call, the test runs successfully

Comment: I think this is correct approach. I would only submit pull request to Robolectric github repository, so anyone could benefit in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robolectric 1.x had poor support for the Android support library. Robolectric 2.0 is significantly better, and has full support for fragments. An alpha was just released today:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
  <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-alpha-1</version>
<dependency>
```